# Oracle load target column from multiple source

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How can I load a target table column by reading or comparing data from two different source columns. I have 2 different sources, source 1 and source 2 with column names status also both tables have employee_id as PK. I want to load my target column with data from source 1 and if data from source 1 column is not available then i should load it from source 2. Is there a way that i can achieve this from plsql?

eg:

```
Source 1
emp id   status
1        A
2        B

source 2 
emp id  status
1       B
3       C

emp source 
emp id   name
1        Mike
2        John
3        Kelly
4        Jake
```

Target    table  emp

```
   emp id   name     status
   1        Mike     A
   2        John     B
   3        Kelly    C
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
select e.emp_id, 
       e.name, 
       case
         when s1.id is not null then s1.status
         else s2.status
       end as status
from emp e
  left join source_1 s1 on e.emp_id = s1.id
  left join source_2 s2 on e.emp_id = s2.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

If a match is commonly found in the first table that you check then you might find this to be a useful optimisation:

```
SELECT e.emp_id,
       e.name,
       coalesce(s1.status, (select s2.status
                              from source2 s2
                             where s2.emp_id = e.emp_id))
FROM emp_source e
  LEFT JOIN source1 s1 ON e.emp_id = s1.emp_id;
```

The coalesce does not execute the select against source2 if a record from source1 was found.

You might write it as:

```
SELECT e.emp_id,
       e.name,
       coalesce((select s1.status
                   from source1 s1
                  where s1.emp_id = e.emp_id),
                (select s2.status
                   from source2 s2
                  where s2.emp_id = e.emp_id))
FROM emp_source e;
```

Answer (score 1):

[a_horse_with_no_name's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16319594/1083652) is a good one, but there is another option -
Instead of using `CASE` use the [COALESCE function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm):

```
SELECT e.emp_id,
       e.name,
       coalesce(s1.status, s2.status)
FROM emp_source e
  LEFT JOIN source1 s1 ON e.emp_id = s1.emp_id
  LEFT JOIN source2 s2 ON e.emp_id = s2.emp_id
WHERE coalesce(s1.status, s2.status) IS NOT NULL;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c985c/5)